# OpenGL - Will using multiple VBO's slow down rendering?

Tags: performance, opengl, vbo

I am rendering some meshes (sometimes upwards of 500) and I wanted to know the best way to approach this. Would it be pointless to create 500 VBOs and then if they pass the frustum and visibility tests, render them. Is there a more efficient way to do this? I am looking to maximize performance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To answer your question, yes, many VBOs will slow things down. More polys will usually slow down the render, but more draw calls has a much greater hit. You want to minimize state changes and draws, as well as the number of buffers you have (and memory use).

I would suggest first looking at the buffers and figuring out how many you *need*. If you can batch/instance geometry, merge static geometry into a single buffer, reuse buffer more efficiently, etc.

Once you've cut the buffers down to the minimum possible, you'll want to use culling of multiple sorts. Visibility, both by frustrum (perhaps in an octree) and occlusion, can provide a significant performance boost. The main idea is to disqualify the geometry as fast and simply as possible, so you start with rough tests (octree), then somewhat more detailed (perhaps an AABB and/or simplified hull), then occlusion, then actually draw.

Here's a [good article on frustrum culling](http://www.flipcode.com/archives/Frustum_Culling.shtml), which touches a bit on quadtrees (and by extension, octrees). Diagrams, explanations and some sample code.

OpenGL occlusion culling articles seem a bit less common, although [this one from GPU Gems](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems/gpugems_ch29.html) might be a good starting place.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am frustum culling using a binary tree and it works fine. I was just more concerned with the fact that having 500 buffers would defeat the whole essence of speed gains associated with VBOs.

Comment: Just so you don't get this wrong: Using several VBOs _in general_ is advantageous (a few dozen at a time), because it allows the GPU to draw from one while uploading another, and moving data between GPU memory and main memory (which the driver sometimes has to do) will be more efficient too, as will be updating data. Just, as peachykeen pointed out, having many hundred of them means changing state many hundred times, which eventually is detrimental.

Comment: Yeah, VBOs are good (you should never be sending geometry across every frame if there's a way to avoid it), but having too many buffers can cause out of memory errors and hurt performance quite significantly. I'm not sure if 500 is *too many*, but it's pushing enough that you might look into cutting it down.

Comment: Thank you both for the reply again. I really appreciate it!